# output of my json response is displaying last item in the database

Tags: android, json, tablelayout

I am trying to display the content of my database in a tablelayout, I have fetch the data from the database, and set it to be displayed in my android app, but when the data displays, it overwrite the data fetch earlier and  only show the last item.

this is an except form my code where I think I got the code wrong

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       /*     TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
            textView.setText(result);*/

         json_string = result;


        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            int count = 0;
            String id, inv_id, refnumber, description, details, qty, unit_price, amount;
            Double subTotal = 00.00;
            int sn = 1;
            Double dAmount;
            while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);

                description = JO.getString("description");

                qty = JO.getString("qty");
                unit_price = JO.getString("unit_price");
                amount = JO.getString("amount");

                txtDescription.setText(description);
                txtQty.setText(qty);
                txtUnit_price.setText(unit_price);
                txtAmount.setText(amount);
                txtsn.setText(String.valueOf(sn));
                count++;
                sn++;


                try {
                    subTotal = subTotal + Double.valueOf(amount);
                    //  dAmount = Double.valueOf(amount);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    subTotal = 00.00;
                }


            }

            txtSubTotal.setText(String.valueOf(subTotal));
            double VAT = 0.05*(subTotal);
            txtVat.setText(String.valueOf(VAT));

            Double Total = VAT + subTotal;

            txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

my XML layout is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ng.proartisan.invoiceapp.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TableRow>
<TextView
    android:text="S/N"
    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"

    />
    <TextView
        android:text="Description"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="QTY"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="Unit Price"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <TextView
        android:text="Amount"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />

</TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sn"
                android:text="S/N"
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"

                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:text="Description"
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/qty"
                android:text="QTY"
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/unit_price"
                android:text="Unit Price"
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/amount"
                android:text="Amount"
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"

                />
            <TextView

                android:text="SubTotal"
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtotal"
                android:text=""
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"

                />
            <TextView

                android:text="VAT"
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vat"
                android:text=""
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"

                />
            <TextView

                android:text="Total"
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView

                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/total"
                android:text=""
                android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>




</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

please help

Comment: thank you for your response, please help out by being more explicit with sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the data into same view in loop, other way to solve your problem like create a new layout and add into your layout example: XML file `layout_item_description.xml`

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_sn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="S/N"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_qty"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="QTY"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_unit_price"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Unit Price"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_amount"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

add this item view to your layout. Your XML Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ng.proartisan.invoiceapp.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:text="S/N"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:text="QTY"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Unit Price"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Amount"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    />
            </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ll_data_description"/>
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                   />
                <TextView
                   android:text="SubTotal"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                   android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subtotal"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                   android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:text="VAT"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/vat"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                   />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                   android:text="Total"
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/total"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="@drawable/cellborder"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Add `LinearLayout ll_data_description = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_data_description);`

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       /*     TextView textView= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
            textView.setText(result);*/

            json_string = result;


            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(json_string);
                jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
                int count = 0;
                String id, inv_id, refnumber, description, details, qty, unit_price, amount;
                Double subTotal = 00.00;
                int sn = 1;
                Double dAmount;
                while (count < jsonArray.length()) {
                    JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);


                    View layout_item_description = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_item_description, null);
                    ((TextView) layout_item_description.findViewById(R.id.tv_sn)).setText(sn+"");

                    description = JO.getString("description");

                    qty = JO.getString("qty");
                    unit_price = JO.getString("unit_price");
                    amount = JO.getString("amount");

                    ((TextView) layout_item_description.findViewById(R.id.tv_description)).setText(sn+"");
                    ((TextView) layout_item_description.findViewById(R.id.tv_qty)).setText(sn+"");
                    ((TextView) layout_item_description.findViewById(R.id.tv_unit_price)).setText(sn+"");
                    ((TextView) layout_item_description.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount)).setText(sn+"");

                    count++;
                    sn++;
                    ll_data_description.addView(layout_item_description);

                    try {
                        subTotal = subTotal + Double.valueOf(amount);
                        //  dAmount = Double.valueOf(amount);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        subTotal = 00.00;
                    }


                }

                txtSubTotal.setText(String.valueOf(subTotal));
                double VAT = 0.05*(subTotal);
                txtVat.setText(String.valueOf(VAT));

                Double Total = VAT + subTotal;

                txtTotal.setText(String.valueOf(Total));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks sis, it's a perfect fit